# How to fix exception when first buliding Room database in kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-room, kotlin-android-extensions

I keep on getting this exception when first creating room database

```
  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Package.getName()' on a null object reference
```

This is my room database code:

```
@Database(entities = [Channel::class], version = 1)
abstract class ChannelRoomDatabase : RoomDatabase() {

    abstract fun channelDao(): ChannelDao

    companion object {
        private var INSTANCE: ChannelRoomDatabase? = null

        fun getInstance(application: Application): ChannelRoomDatabase? {
            if (INSTANCE == null) {

                    INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(application,
                            ChannelRoomDatabase::class.java,
                            "channels")
                            .build()
            }

            return INSTANCE
        }
    }

}
```

And the gradle code:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

    def room_version = "1.1.1"

    implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:$room_version"
    kapt "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:$room_version"
```

Also I get this error when buliding the project:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin'.

Folder /home/Desktop/MySendBird/app/build/generated/source/kaptKotlin/debug


Folder /home/Desktop/MySendBird/app/build/generated/source/kaptKotlin/release


3rd-party Gradle plug-ins may be the cause
```

What could be the reason? I have seen similar questions here but no any clue. Please help!

Update! In my Dao I get this error

[image]

So how to make @Query understand that it I give it a java String not Kotlin String

See also the stacktrace:

```
/home/Desktop/MySendBird/app/build/tmp/kapt3/stubs/debug/ChannelRoomDatabase.java:6: warning: Schema export directory is not provided to the annotation processor so we cannot export the schema. You can either provide `room.schemaLocation` annotation processor argument OR set exportSchema to false.
public abstract class ChannelRoomDatabase extends android.arch.persistence.room.RoomDatabase {
                ^
:app:compileDebugKotlin
w: /home/Desktop/MySendBird/app/src/main/java/com/example/anna/mysendbird/repository/ChannelRepository.kt: (16, 13): Variable 'db' is never used
w: /home/Desktop/MySendBird/app/src/main/java/com/example/anna/mysendbird/repository/ChannelRepository.kt: (47, 23): Parameter 'channel' is never used
w: /home/Desktop/MySendBird/app/src/main/java/com/example/anna/mysendbird/view/MainActivity.kt: (179, 29): Parameter 'userId' is never used
```

See the similar questions:

[using Room with kotlin, get exception when build the database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46415054/using-room-with-kotlin-get-exception-when-build-the-database)

[Null object reference when I try to build room](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49813715/null-object-reference-when-i-try-to-build-room)

Comment: Can you share code for `ChannelDao` and stack trace in build error?. Stack trace can be found in non graphic mode of build section.

Comment: @adityakamble49 thank you very much for the clue, please see my Dao, it did not showing this error before though, I would notice it for sure

Comment: Glad it helped. Can you share code for `ChannelDao` ? Which error it is showing now?

Comment: @adityakamble49 just edited, you can view now

Comment: Looks like lint error, Maybe because of kotlin plugin and kotlin version are different. Try with clean build

Comment: @adityakamble49 very strange behaviour, now I don't get the error in Dao, but get a build error, please see in the new edit

Comment: Its build error, can you share stack trace? Stack trace can be found in non graphic mode of build section

Comment: @adityakamble49 build stack trace shows what I have shared already

Comment: Refer this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/45016580/3624647

Comment: @adityakamble49 thanks for guidance, see the update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting Android Room schema directory error

```
/home/Desktop/MySendBird/app/build/tmp/kapt3/stubs/debug/ChannelRoomDatabase.java:6: warning: Schema export directory is not provided to the annotation processor so we cannot export the schema. You can either provide `room.schemaLocation` annotation processor argument OR set exportSchema to false.
public abstract class ChannelRoomDatabase extends android.arch.persistence.room.RoomDatabase {
```

**Schema export directory is not provided to the annotation processor**

You need to add schema directory to your **app's gradle.build** as below,

```
android {

    defaultConfig {
        javaCompileOptions {
            annotationProcessorOptions {
                arguments = ["room.schemaLocation": "$projectDir/schemas".toString()]
            }
        }
    }

}
```

This will tell your Room annotation processor to generate Database schema and put it under directory mentioned under `"room.schemaLocation"`

Comment: tried but got this: Could not find method javaCompileOptions() for arguments [build_6of96zof7e6pmo2m5c469pv1u$_run_closure1$_closure5@25dac170] on object of type com.android.build.gradle.AppExtension.

Comment: btw I first tried this option: exportSchema = false  and didn't help

Comment: `dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
}`

Comment: `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip`

Comment: @sunflower20, Versions looks correct. My bad, I have updated location code above, as it should be under `defaultConfig` try it and let me know

Comment: no problem I put it in defaultConfig after, but still the same

Comment: Try with clean rebuild

Comment: I just created new Database with new name and the problem resolved!(clean and build didn't help), Thank you very much, you saved me!

Comment: Glad it helped :)